# String to Date Conversion inside Rails Where Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query like this:

```
User.where("medical_card_expiry_date BETWEEN ? AND ?",Time.now.to_date,(Time.now+10.years).to_date)
```

This query would have worked fine if the `medical_card_expiry_date` was in `Date` format,but unfortunately its a `String` and hence will not produce the expected result.

Can i convert the `medical_card_expiry_date` to `Date` insdide the where clause itself?Is there a method in Rails so that I could make this work?

Comment: Can you definitely not fix the database schema? Storing date/time values as strings is horrible. If that's completely unfixable, what format are you using?

Comment: Convert `medical_card_expiry_date` to date type

Comment: I know its horrible to save date/time values as string.Its like the db schema is a bit complex now and lot of other methods uses this value and hence if I change the db schema it is not feasible in the current scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing Rails can do for you in your query, you need to ask the database to do the conversion when it uses the field.
You can use `STR_TO_DATE` in MySQL (if that's what you're using, otherwise find the relevant alternative method) like so:

```
User.where("STR_TO_DATE(medical_card_expiry_date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN ? AND ?",Time.now.to_date,(Time.now+10.years).to_date)
```

Based on comments, here is a Postgres version

```
User.where("to_date(medical_card_expiry_date, 'DD MM YY') BETWEEN ? AND ?",Time.now.to_date,(Time.now+10.years).to_date)
```

You will need to alter the format element (`DD MM YY`) based on what is actually stored in your database. Guidelines can be found here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: This doesnt work,gave an error
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function str_to_date(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @SoorajChandu, Matt said explicitly that it's for MySQL.

Comment: @SoorajChandu Updated with Postgres version.